# How do I access the ApplicationContext from a service within the micronaut framework?

Tags: java, spring, consul, micronaut

Every attempt I have made to access the ApplicationContext in my service has failed with the ApplicationContext being returned as null.  In Spring I was able to use ApplicationContextAware which according to (https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-spring/latest/guide/index.html) should be replaced with @Autowired in micronaut.  I have attempted

```
@Autowired ApplicationContext context
```

with no luck however.  It is always null.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The second paragraph seems like a whole separate issue.  Are you asking how to get a reference to the `ApplicationContext` or are you asking how to get the names of all services registered with a Consul instance?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  I have edited the question to be more precise and can follow up with additional questions.  Looking at the test cases for micronaut I saw that the application context was leveraged to access the Consul Client and Discovery Client.  My end goal is to get the list of service ids from one of those services.  I am failing at what I believe is the first step, getting access to the application context since unlike the test cases, I am attempting to wire in the application context into my service.

Comment: Here is a link to a sample micronaut test case https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/afc3fb377fea37f942c1a251be19b58f9f989b22/discovery-client/src/test/groovy/io/micronaut/discovery/consul/ConsulMockHealthStatusSpec.groovy

Comment: You can have the `ApplicationContext` injected into your service by way of a constructor parameter, or by way of a property marked with `@javax.inject.Inject`.  Is that really what you want though, or do you really just want to inject a bean that is in the context?

Comment: It isn't clear why you are referencing `@Autowired`.  is this a Spring project in which you are trying to use Micronaut?  If not, `@Autowired` probably shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: I added an answer below that addresses the question currently in the text above.  This addresses that question, but doesn't address how to get a list of service ids from Consul, which is a separate question and does not have to involve injecting the `ApplicationContext` anywhere.

Comment: This was extremely helpful and it shows that something is awry in my build as your example does what I was expecting.  Could you elaborate on the alternative for getting the service ids from Consul that does not involve the ApplicationContext?  I would love to avoid the ApplicationContext altogether but coming from Spring it was my fallback :-)  TIA!

Comment: "Could you elaborate on the alternative for getting the service ids from Consul that does not involve the ApplicationContext?" - I included an example of how to do it in my answer below.

Comment: "I would love to avoid the ApplicationContext altogether but coming from Spring it was my fallback" - Using Spring you also would not need to inject the `ApplicationContext` in order to do this.  You could use an approach similar to what I included in the answer below which is to inject the bean that can retrieve the ids, no need to inject that `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectcontext shows 2 ways to inject the `ApplicationContext`.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectcontext/blob/1f319a3bb3db8eff05f159dd8dc642b227662307/src/main/java/injectcontext/FirstService.java

```
package injectcontext;

import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class FirstService {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public FirstService(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public boolean isContextNull() {
        return applicationContext == null;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectcontext/blob/1f319a3bb3db8eff05f159dd8dc642b227662307/src/main/java/injectcontext/SecondService.java

```
package injectcontext;

import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class SecondService {

    @Inject
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public boolean isContextNull() {
        return applicationContext == null;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectcontext/blob/1f319a3bb3db8eff05f159dd8dc642b227662307/src/main/java/injectcontext/DemoController.java

```
package injectcontext;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

@Controller("/")
public class DemoController {

    FirstService firstService;

    SecondService secondService;

    public DemoController(FirstService firstService, SecondService secondService) {
        this.firstService = firstService;
        this.secondService = secondService;
    }

    @Get("/first")
    public String first() {
        boolean isNull = firstService.isContextNull();

        return "firstService.isContextNull() == " + isNull;
    }

    @Get("/second")
    public String second() {
        boolean isNull = secondService.isContextNull();

        return "secondService.isContextNull() == " + isNull;
    }
}
```

That all works:

```
 $ curl http://localhost:8080/first
firstService.isContextNull() == false
 $ 
 $ curl http://localhost:8080/second
secondService.isContextNull() == false
```

**EDIT**

If what you really want is to just retrieve the service ids, you can do something like this:

```
package injectcontext;

import io.micronaut.discovery.DiscoveryClient;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.List;

@Singleton
public class DiscoveryHelper {

    private final DiscoveryClient consulClient;

    public DiscoveryHelper(DiscoveryClient consulClient) {
        this.consulClient = consulClient;
    }

    public Publisher<List<String>> getIds() {
        // do whatever you want with the ids...
        return consulClient.getServiceIds();
    }
}
```

That will work if you have that in a service that has consul enabled.

```
consul:
  client:
    registration:
      enabled: false # set to true if you want this service to register itself
    defaultZone: "${CONSUL_HOST:localhost}:${CONSUL_PORT:8500}"
```